# How use bulk action (VBO) with table pagination?

Tags: views

I have a table result with *n* pages. I would like to be able to select checkboxes from several different pages of results and then execute a bulk operation. However, when I have selected a checkbox and go to the next page my previous choices are lost. How can I keep my choices saved across page loads?

Answer (score 1):

This is only supported in the Drupal 6 version of VBO (the option is called "Preserve selection across pages" and I think it's enabled by default).
There's an open issue request for the Drupal 7 version: http://drupal.org/node/1207348
This is not a priority for me so I don't see it fixed in the next few months (unless someone else takes the lead).

Comment: just a quick update on this one, in case it is still of interest.
There is a proof-of-concept patch for this, available at https://www.drupal.org/node/1207348 cheers, stef

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis cool. I've used ViewsSend and also Views Row Selector ... the problem I see trying to implement this is for write heavy content. The selectall would either have to be a flag "select all upon form submission" or "use only the IDs i've selected" because Views isn't ajax enabled by default you could have had submissions of data between selecting your view rows and when you run your submit action.